# Creating an array or list or collection of children of an abstract base class

Tags: c#, arrays, strong-typing

Trying to help a friend out here. I'm not a Microsoft programmer.

```
public abstract class Foo {}
public class Bar : Foo {}
public class Baz : Foo {}
```

This seems to work pretty well then in another class he can instantiate arrays of `Bar`, and `Baz` like this

```
public class MyClass {
  Bar[] Bars = new Bar[] { new Bar[] { new Bar(), new Bar() } }
  Baz[] Bazs = new Baz[] { new Baz[] { new Baz(), new Baz() } }
}
```

the question is if he wants to have an accessor that returns `Foos` and `Bars` how does he do it?

```
public class MyClass {
  Bar[] Bars = new Bar[] { new Bar[] { new Bar(), new Bar() } }
  Baz[] Bazs = new Baz[] { new Baz[] { new Baz(), new Baz() } }
  public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos() {
    // No go.
    return [ Bars, Bazs ];

    // Also No go.
    List<Foo> test = new List<Foo> { Bars, Bazs };
    return test;
  }
}
```

I think Microsoft normally implements this with interfaces, but his assignment calls for using abstract base classes. Is there a way to return a List or Array of children of an abstract base class?

Comment: In both scenarios, you can't create an instance of 'new Foo()' as 'Foo' is an abstract class. You can create objects of Bar and Baz and return an array of Foo. See if below answer helps.

Comment: There apears to be a syntax error in your code: to create an array use `Bar[] Bars = new Bar[] { new Bar(), new Bar() }` you seem to create some sort of nested array with `new Bar[] { new Bar[] {...`

Answer (score 0):

In both scenarios, you can't create an instance of 'new Foo()' as 'Foo' is an abstract class. You can create objects of Bar and Baz and return an array of Foo. See if below answer helps.

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        Foo[] Foos1 = new Foo[] { new Bar(), new Bar() };
        Foo[] Foos2 = new Foo[] { new Baz(), new Baz() };

        // OR use as below

        /*
        Foo[] Foos1 = new Bar[] { new Bar(), new Bar() };
        Foo[] Foos2 = new Baz[] { new Baz(), new Baz() };
        */

        public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos1()
        {
            // Works.
            return Foos1;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos2()
        {
            // Works
            List<Foo> test = new List<Foo>();
            test.AddRange(Foos2);
            return test;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there anyway to keep Foos1, and Foos2 strongly typed at that point of the code, and to make it still work? Or, do I have type them to the ABC there?

Comment: Not sure, if I understood the problem clearly. If you can explain the problem/scenario you are trying to solve, that will be helpful. You can replace first 2 lines of above problem as in the updated answer also.

Comment: In this, you lose the typing information before the point you return from the function -- when you declare that `Foo[] Foos1` if I wanted to declare Foos1 to be of type Bar[], could I do that at that point and then later cast or something to Foo?

Comment: Also, I'm declaring Foo to be an abstract base class, I'm getting that List<Foo> does not contain a constructor?

Comment: Yes, if we need to return as Foo[] needs to cast to Bar[] or Baz[] later if you want to access some functionalities specific fo Bar or Baz. Otherwise can directly use as Foo (if you are not planning to access any specific functionalities of Bar or Baz).

Answer (score 0):

In order to add another IEnumerable'T to a List you have to use "AddRange" like:

```cs
List<Foo> test = new List<Foo>();
test.AddRange(Foos);
test.AddRange(Bars);

return test;
```

You can also use the List constructor overload in order to add an existing IEnumerable'T to your list:

```cs
List<Foo> test = new List<Foo>(Foos);
test.AddRange(Bars);

return test;
```

Comment: bottom doesn't work because Foo is an abstract base class and doesn't have a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make a copy of your arrays. The following code will generate an `IEnumerable<Foo>` that always reflects the current content of your arrays, and does not consume any significant amount of memory:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Bar[] Bars = new Bar[] {new Bar(), new Bar()};
    private Baz[] Bazs = new Baz[] {new Baz(), new Baz()};

    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos()
    {
        // Cast Bars as an Enumerable<Foo>, then append Bazs 
        // (no need to explicitly cast Bazs)
        return Bars.AsEnumerable<Foo>().Concat(Bazs);

        // or

        // Create an empty Enumerable<Foo>, then append Bazs and Bars
        return Enumerable.Empty<Foo>().Concat(Bars).Concat(Bazs);
    }
}
```

The object returned by GetFoos() here is just a reference to the two original arrays. Whenever code enumerates this IEnumerable, it will implicitly access the two original arrays. So if, after GetFoos() is called, but before the result form GetFoos() is used, someone replaces every item of `Bars` with NULL, then the code that called GetFoos() will see only a bunch of NULL.

If you do not want the content of the returned IEnumerable to change whenever you change the content of the original arrays, you will need to create a copy, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos()
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<Foo>().Concat(Bars.ToArray()).Concat(Bazs.ToArray());
}
```